# How to replace characters at PathVariable in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I tried a couple of solutions but was unable to solve it. I looking for a solution where I can replace special characters in Path Variable in Spring Boot.

**Example**

```
xyz.com/3233+23+232+323
```

I am looking for a possible solution where Spring `@PathVariable` returns me the String "323323232323" *without* **+ sign**.

I know I can do a simple String replace, but there are 100's of API's and it will be difficult to do that.

I am looking for something with minimal changes required.

Comment: Write a filter and put it in front of every request. Read the request parameters and do the changes in there before proceeding from the filter. Also, you will have to implement MultiHttpServletRequest and response classes in order to be able to read the request multiple times. It is an hour or so job, hence not providing full code but the solution idea.

Answer (score 1):

One way, just read the @PathVariable value, then apply a regular expression.

Just One line, Example:

```
       @GetMapping("/read/{str}")
        public String check(@PathVariable String str){
            String modifiedStr = str.replaceAll("\\+", "");
            return modifiedStr;
        }
```

Sample: `http://localhost:8080/ticket-service/read/3233+23+232+323`

Output: 323323232323